# SQL - joining data

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Is it possible to get 1 result where I require data from 3 tables.

First table: I will need to grab all the fields (1 row found by a primary key)

Second table: I will need to grab the field 'username' (connected to first table by 'master_id')

Third table: I will need to grab the latest added row with the associated master_id key (table has 'date', 'master_id', 'previous_name').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select top 1 first.*, second.username, third.*
from first 
inner join second on first.id = second.master_id
inner join third on first.id = third.master_id
order by
third.date desc
```

As always there are dozens of ways to skin a cat, I'm not sure if this is optimized as the subquery methods, but it should work.

Comment: Oh, only one row! Well played, sir!

Answer (score 1):

You can join the three tables together.  Then, you can use a "filter" join to keep only the latest Table3 row:

```
select  *
from    Table1 t1
join    Table2 t2
on      t2.master_id = t1.master_id
join    Table3 t3
on      t3.master_id = t1.master_id
join    (
        select  master_id
        ,       max(date) as max_date
        from    Table3
        group by
                master_id
        ) as filter
on      t3.master_id = filter.master_id
        and t3.date = filter.max_date
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a correlated subquery for that third table.

```
SELECT t1.*, username, date, previous_name
FROM FirstTable t1
INNER JOIN SecondTable t2 ON t1.master_id=t2.master_id
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT master_id, date, previous_name
 FROM ThirdTable AS t3_1
 WHERE date = (
      SELECT MAX(date) 
      FROM ThirdTable AS t3_2 
      WHERE t3_2.master_id=t3_1.master_id)) q1 ON q1.master_id=t1.master_id;
```

NOTE: Untested.

Comment: An uncorrelated subquery works too, see my answer.  The correlated query should do better for small amounts of rows, especially if there is an index on `master_id`